# Why an async Action I passed to Task.Run() is not awaited?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

I have really strange feeling here that I am missing something, but am struggling over the problem for a few hours now and can't get it. I have a kind of task scheduling class that mostly receives normal synchronous operations that it launches than asynchronously via Task.Run(). But when it gets an asynchronous Action passed it returns back without waiting for task to be awaited. I have simplified it to the following example:

```
private async void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Logger("Click event received");
    await OperationProcessor(async () =>
    {
        Logger(">>> Starting ACTION, waiting 5 seconds");
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Logger(">>> ACTION finished");
    });
    Logger("Click event finished");
}

private static async Task OperationProcessor(Action operation)
{
    Logger("Processing started, waiting a second");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Logger("Launching action");
    await Task.Run(operation);
    Logger("Returned from action, waiting another second");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Logger("Processing finished");
}

private static void Logger(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss} [{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}] {message}");
}
```

This produces following output:

```
1: 16.07.19 10:58:06 [1] Click event received
2: 16.07.19 10:58:06 [1] Processing started, waiting a second
3: 16.07.19 10:58:07 [1] Launching action
4: 16.07.19 10:58:07 [7] >>> Starting ACTION, waiting 5 seconds
5: 16.07.19 10:58:07 [1] Returned from action, waiting another second
6: 16.07.19 10:58:08 [1] Processing finished
7: 16.07.19 10:58:08 [1] Click event finished
8: 16.07.19 10:58:12 [7] >>> ACTION finished
```

How to make 5 wait for action started at 4?

Comment: Task.Run wraps your operations in a thread so you are awaiting the task that fires off your task not the task itself as your action is a self contained thread already you just need to invoke the action not wrap it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you are passing in an async call you don't then need to rewrap it in a thread

for an action all you need to do is

```
private static async Task OperationProcessor(Action operation)
{
    Logger("Processing started, waiting a second");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Logger("Launching action");
    operation();
    Logger("Returned from action, waiting another second");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Logger("Processing finished");
}
```

however as you have spotted the signature for an async action is returning a task so the same operation for a async call would be

```
private static async Task OperationProcessor(Func<Task> operation)
{
    Logger("Processing started, waiting a second");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Logger("Launching action");
    await operation();
    Logger("Returned from action, waiting another second");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Logger("Processing finished");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That sorted out my mind :) Although I was already near to the solution myself. I was disoriented because my method was written mostly for synchronous methods, so wrapping was necessary there. I ended up making a separate overload for asynchronous Actions. Thanks.

Comment: @Programmierus by declaring OperationProcessor as async and then invoking the syncronous method inside it you are actually duplicating the wrapping process that the task.run does, that is mostly used to get rid of the aysnc not awaiting warning you get with out an await as you are awiting the delays then that warning wouldn't be appearing

Comment: if you were passing in several syncronous operations and wanted to run all of them async and then return after all have completed then that would require task.run of course

Answer (score 6):

> Why an async Action I passed to Task.Run() is not awaited?

Because it's not possible to `await` a `void`.

It's common to *talk* about "awaiting a method" or "awaiting a delegate", but that can be misleading. What actually happens is that the method is called first, and then whatever it *returns* is awaited. And it's not possible to await the result of an `Action` because that delegate returns `void`.

This is the primary reason why it's good to [avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). In this case, the `async void` was sneaky because it was a lambda expression.

The async equivalent of `void Method()` is `async Task MethodAsync()`, so the [asynchronous delegate equivalent of `Action` is `Func<Task>`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html). This is why adding the `Func<Task>` overload worked. You can keep both the `Action` and `Func<Task>` overloads, and the compiler will intelligently prefer the `Func<Task>` overload for `async` lambdas.

> I have a kind of task scheduling class

If your `Func<Task>` solution is good enough, then keep that as-is. But if you want to go a bit deeper, it is *possible* to detect (and wait for) `async void` methods. `async void` methods [interact with the current `SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx). Since you have your own "scheduling class", you **might** want to consider providing a `SynchronizationContext` for code that is scheduled by that class. If you're interested, feel free to borrow from my [`AsyncContext` class](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/tree/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context) which is essentially just a single-threaded work queue with a `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: Dear Stephen, thank you very much! I definitely learnt a lot of new stuff today from you. Going to research the topic tomorrow in detail, for this evening I am done :) And thanks for the time you invested!

Answer (score 0):

Got it... Changing the method signature does the thing:

```
    private static async Task OperationProcessor(Func<Task> operation) {
         // Body unchanged
    }
```